# Delphi: Create a string from image and add to memo

Tags: image, delphi, stream

I have a picture in a TImage component.  I need to convert that image into a string and place it in a TMemo component. How to?

Comment: I assume you mean `String` instead of `Stream`?  A picture is binary data (and `TImage` can hold pictures in many different binary formats), so what exactly do you expect to show in the Memo?  Please provide more information about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'll explain further, let's take as an example the following image:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Williamsburg,Brooklyn,NY&zoom=13&size=400x400&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C11211%7C11206%7C11222&sensor=true_or_false

If we use the element inpecionar browser will see that it is a string that has 80 thousand characters and so ends (....2s/w/YjpBGIG5P3QAAAABJRU5ErkJggg ==) what I need is to pick up all this text that represents the image and place in a memo field.

Comment: Look for Base64 encoder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code may be like this.

```
implementation
uses
  EncdDecd;
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ss    :TMemoryStream;
begin
  ss   :=TMemoryStream.Create();
  try
    Image1.Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(ss);
    Memo1.Text  :=  EncodeBase64(ss.Memory, ss.Size);
  finally
    ss.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Note that `EncodeBase64()` forces a line break every 75 characters.  If you don't want that, you will have to strip them out manually, or use a different encoder that does not produce line breaks, like Indy's `TIdEncoderMIME` class, eg: `Memo1.Text := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeStream(ss);` or `TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeStream(ss, Memo1.Lines);`